# Faceted serach - refresh filters on select list value change

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1, oracle-apex-19.2

I have custom select list, after change value I call Dynamic Action and refresh my classic report Search Results.

How refresh Faceted serach filters (on the left side) after refresh clasic report?

Note: This is only demo I need my custom select list like this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create 2 actions for your dynamic action.

- One to refresh the results region, which is the classic report
- One to refresh the faceted search region itself

Tested this on 22.2 with a dynamic action like you described and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, working fine on 22.2 but on  20.1 not working!

Comment: Time to upgrade :)